# How can I pass data from one app to another app in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am developing an app in which payment automation is an functionality.
What is required is that Account details need to be filled by my app, so that no need of manual typing.
I know I can open app using url_launcher package, but I don't know how to pass data?
and how to map data with the different textfield of the selected app .

Comment: Can you be more specific about the data you want to pass? Is it related to the payment information and can you also name the app in which you want to pass the data ?

Comment: Yeah, it is related to payment information like account number.

Comment: Any payment app, needs to be selected by the user.

Comment: Well you don't have to do this manual most of the dependencies offer you this functionality by default.

Comment: Can you please suggest me some dependencies or packages?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to consider any UPI enabled payment application here and you want to pass data like reciever name, upi ID, total amount and a transactional note.

```
Future<UpiResponse> initiateTransaction(UpiApp app) async {
    return _upiIndia.startTransaction(
      app: app,
      receiverUpiId: "9078600498@ybl",
      receiverName: 'Md Azharuddin',
      transactionRefId: 'TestingUpiIndiaPlugin',
      transactionNote: 'Not actual. Just an example.',
      amount: 1.00,
    );
  }
```

You can use [upi_india](https://pub.dev/packages/upi_india) but this is not limited to just upi_india.
You have other packages like [stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) and [flutter pay](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pay) which also has similar functionality

Comment: Oh, Upi_india doesn't work with some apps like Google Pay, PhonePe, Paytm .

Comment: I need peer to peer to transaction. Does flutter_pay and stripe works for it.